# why square root of a positive number is positive?

Tags: calculus

We have $(+3)^2=(-3)^2=9$. But why do we define

$$\sqrt 9=+3?$$
Why $\sqrt9=-3$ is false?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want $\sqrt{\cdot}$ to be a function on nonnegative reals.  To be a function, it must have exactly one value for each input, and the most natural one to choose is the positive one.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there are two $a's$ such that $a^2=9$. Instead of saying "Please give me the positive number $a$ such that $a^2=9$, we write $\sqrt{9}$. It's short-hand for the longer sentence.

If we more often cared about getting the negative number $a$ such that $a^2=9$, we might come up with special notation for that case.

Comment: To get the negative number, you'd just write $-\sqrt\cdot$ rather than $\sqrt\cdot$.