# Why does a root only have a positive output?

Tags: exponentiation, quadratics, radicals

Let's say I am solving an equation, and end up with this:

> x^2 = 16

The solutions will be

> x=4 or x=-4

That makes sense.
But when I have this:

> x = √16

The only solution is

> x=4

Because roots do not have negative outcomes. 
But when I solve x^2 = 16, what I actually do is take the root of 16 and that is my answer. Can anyone explain this? And why do square roots only have positive answers?

Comment: Also [Why is the even root of a number always positive?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41878/856), [Can the square root of a real number be negative?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/809424/856), [Square root confusion?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448885/856) We seem to have a lot of these.

Comment: You should go from $$x^2=16$$ to $$x = \pm\sqrt{16}$$ so you recover both solutions.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954153/why-square-root-of-a-positive-number-is-positive?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380359/why-is-sqrt4-2-and-not-pm-2?lq=1 (some of which are already marked as duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol refers to *one* of the square roots.  The fact that we call it "the" square root" instead of "the positive square root when one exists" is inaccurate laziness but coloquially understood.

So the solution*S* to $x^2 = 16$ *are* both 4 (which is $\sqrt {16}$) *AND* -4 (which is $-\sqrt{16}$) and we frequently write it as $\pm\sqrt{16}$)

=====

Note: $x^2 = 16$ and $x = \sqrt{16}$ are two different statements altogether.  They are *related* statements but still different.  In getting from $x^2 = 16$ to $x = \sqrt{16}$,  we could just as easily have gone to the statement $-x = \sqrt{16}$.

If we want to be pedantic about it, the proper statement should have been $\pm x = \pm \sqrt{16}$ however these four statements are redundant, so simply $x = \pm \sqrt{16}$ suffices.  (Although techinally $\pm x =  \sqrt{16}$ is equally valid.)

Answer (score 1):

Remember this always :
If $y^2=x$ then, $\sqrt{x}=|y|$,. Since y satisfies both positive and negative values we have them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a convention to make $\sqrt{} $ a function. A function can only have one value for each input, so for every positive real $x$ we define $\sqrt{x}$ as the *positive* real number such that $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$.